# Как при прохождении цикла каждый раз создавать новый список?

Tags: python, list

```
n = int(input)
for i in range(0, n):
    a = input()
    Создать новый список при каждом проходе цикла
```

Благодарю за внимание.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Увы, но можно только создать список, в котором будут каждый раз создаваться новые

```
arr = []
n = int(input)
for i in range(0, n):
    a = input()
    b = [a]
    arr.append(b) #в наш список добавляется другой список b, в котором лежит значение a
```

Answer (score 4):

в одну строку

```
arr = [[input()] for _ in range(int(input()))]
```

Comment: Нет, чтобы при 1-ом проходе создавался arr1, при 2-ом arr2 и так далее.

Answer (score 2):

Добавлю вариант со словарём. Сначала обычная версия:

```
d = {}
n = int(input())
for i in range(0, n):
    a = input()
    d[i+1] = a.split()
```

После заполнения к элементам словаря можно обращаться вот так:

```
print(d[1]) # первый список в словаре
```

И версия с тем же словарём в одну строку:

```
d = {i: input().split() for i in range(1, int(input()))}
```

В Python можно и прямо переменным `arr1`, `arr2` и т.д. в цикле присвоить значения через `globals()['arr' + str(i)] = ...`, но так делать неправильно, для однотипных объектов лучше использовать какую-либо коллекцию - `list`, `dict`.